# How to dynamically change Spring JdbcTemplate DataSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I have a config file with default settings for JDBC connection.

**Is there any option to edit this default connection details once application is running?** After all beans has been created (edit connection details in the controller).

Scenario:

- user starts the application, and can edit connection details by going to 
  localhost:8080/myapp/db/edit
- fills in connection details and saves new database details

This should then find existing connections, update connection details and reinstantiate beans.

Comment: "User" in this case is some kind of admin user, or every user will be able to set a different data source to his account, like a 'preference'?

Comment: any / every user - user :-)

Comment: If the ammount of users is small enough, I would go with a custom written data source provider mechanism, looking up connection properties from the settings database on a per user basis, opening and closing a connection on every request, providing an API to reset 'cached' values when the users update's his info. Otherwise, if there will be a lot of concurrent users, you should take far more precautions, as opening/closing a connection on every request (my suggestion) may not have an acceptable performance at all.

Comment: yes this is what I am doing now, thanks.

Comment: DataSource is supplied through constructor to 'JdbcTemplate', so definetly you need to extend and write your own custom implementation, if you have fixed number of databases I would suggest using factory pattern to lookup DataSource required by current user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing beans from `Spring Container` and re initiating them.

```
    Demo demo = getBean(context);

    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory = context
            .getBeanFactory();

    BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) configurableListableBeanFactory;
    // Removing the bean from container
    beanDefinitionRegistry.removeBeanDefinition("demo");

    // Trying to obtains bean again from container. This will throw a null     
    demo = getBean(context);
    //demo object will be null here

    // Creating and registering bean to the container      
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(Demo.class);
    beanDefinition.setAttribute("name", "name");

    beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("demo", beanDefinition);
    context.refresh();

    //Obtaining from container again
    demo = getBean(context);
```